# gradle build fails while running rocket chat kotlin sdk in Android studio 3.2-beta 1 and throws below error

Tags: rocket.chat

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'rocket.chat.kotlin.sdk'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.51/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.51.pom'.
  >   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.51/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.51.pom'.
  >   Connect to 10.53.130.55:80 [/10.53.130.55] failed: connect timed out
  >   Could not resolve gradle.plugin.org.jmailen.gradle:kotlinter-gradle:1.11.2.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve gradle.plugin.org.jmailen.gradle:kotlinter-gradle:1.11.2.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/gradle/plugin/org/jmailen/gradle/kotlinter-gradle/1.11.2/kotlinter-gradle-1.11.2.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/gradle/plugin/org/jmailen/gradle/kotlinter-gradle/1.11.2/kotlinter-gradle-1.11.2.pom'.
  >   Connect to 10.53.130.55:80 [/10.53.130.55] failed: connect timed out
  >   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:0.9.16.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:0.9.16.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/dokka/dokka-gradle-plugin/0.9.16/dokka-gradle-plugin-0.9.16.pom'.
  >   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/dokka/dokka-gradle-plugin/0.9.16/dokka-gradle-plugin-0.9.16.pom'.
  >   Connect to 10.53.130.55:80 [/10.53.130.55] failed: connect timed out
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 10s
Cause: connect timed out